# Using dropdown geometry selection as a variable in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, dropdownlist

I have two dropdowns where the second one depends on the selection of the first one.
They work ok, however, I would like to use the geometry of the selected dropdown (**second one**) as a variable/geometry that will allow me to do calculations on it.

```js
var moatzaNames = agri_fields.aggregate_array('Moatza').distinct().sort();
var fieldNum = agri_fields.aggregate_array('ID_fields').sort();

// SELECT A MOATZA FROM DROP DOWN SELECT WIDGET
var moatzaSelect = ui.Select({
  items: moatzaNames.getInfo(),
  placeholder: ('Select Moatza'),
  style: {width: '120px'},
  onChange: function getMoatza(key) {
    print(key);  //print the selected Moatza
    var selectedpolys = agri_fields.filterMetadata('Moatza','equals',key);
    var selectedFieldsNames = selectedpolys.aggregate_array('ID_field').sort();  
    print("selected Fields Names", selectedFieldsNames); 
    Map.addLayer(selectedpolys,{color:'gray'},'selectedpolys');
    

    // PASS THE FIELDS NAMES TO THE ITEMS FOR THE NEXT DROP DOWN LIST
    selectedFieldsNames.evaluate(function(values) {
    fieldSelect.items().reset(values);
    fieldSelect.setValue(values[0], false);
});
  }
});


// SELECT AREA OF INTEREST FROM DROP DOWN SELECT WIDGET
var fieldSelect = ui.Select({
  placeholder: ('Select field'),
  style: {width: '120px'},
  onChange: display
});


//This function will be called when the user changes the value in the dropdown
function display(fieldSelect){
  var selected = agri_fields.filter(
    ee.Filter.eq('ID_field',fieldSelect))
  var geometry = selected.geometry();
  print(fieldSelect, geometry);
  
  Map.clear();
  Map.addLayer(geometry,{color:'black'},fieldSelect);
  Map.centerObject(geometry, 17);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// ------->>>>> I would like to use the result of the last dropdown (fieldSelect)
/// as a variable/polygon that can be used for spatial statistics and index calculation like NDVI
/// which means, I would like to get the geometry and use is instead of the next two lines:


// /// Choose the field ID
var field1 = "ID == 42572";
var geometry = agri_fields.filter(field1);
```

Here is the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/05a8c7e05d1e317fe4e540bc08d92031

Comment: to be able to reproduce the error you should share users/yaronogen/agri_selected_test

Comment: Here is the modified link:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/05a8c7e05d1e317fe4e540bc08d92031

Comment: It's still not shared, please check the "anyone can read" box in the asset's share settings. See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager#sharing-assets

Comment: The asset is shared. Thanks

Comment: You get the geometry in your `display` function. You could add more functionality to that function - do the calculations inside of the function. You could make `geometry` a global variable and update it when you get the geometry in the `display` function, but I think it would be better to handle calculations inside `display` function.

Comment: Hi Justin, Do you know how exactly can I do it?